# A Perl script and a Perl module are using `use lib` and referencing the same module

Tags: perl

I have a Perl script that is using two modules. The first module also uses the second module.

If the first module does `use lib 'dir1'`, and the script does `use lib 'dir2'`:

module1.pm

```
use lib "dir1";
use module2;
```

script.pl

```
use lib "dir2";
use module1;
use module2;
```

which directory is being used by the first module? Does the script's `use lib, 'dir2'` override the `use lib, 'dir1'` in the first module, or do they have different scope?

I did my own testing, and printed the @INC inside module1.pm and script.pl, the result was the dir1 was at the top of @INC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`lib`](http://perldoc.perl.org/lib.html) pragma just does an [`unshift`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unshift.html) of the path onto the global (and package-independent) array [`@INC`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html). Nothing is ever removed from `@INC` unless it is done explicitly.

The first time it is encountered is on the first line of the `script.pl`, so thereafter `@INC` will contain `dir2`.

The next thing that happens is that `script.pl` compiles and runs `module1.pm`. (It will look for it in `dir2` first, and then in the directories that were originally in `@INC`.) The first line of that file contains another `use lib`, which will `unshift @INC, 'dir1'`.

Thereafter `@INC` stays the same. Any further [`use`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html) or [`require`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/require.html) will look in `dir1` first (because it was shifted last) then `dir2`, and then in the rest of `@INC`.

Comment: Cool! Thanks for the explanation! To add more on this, behaviour is different when you put use lib inside BEGIN{}.

Comment: @miss_a: No, the behaviour would be just the same. Any `use` statement is already inside its own implicit `BEGIN` block.

Comment: Yep you're right, didn't realize there was something wrong in my testing. :) thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

You obviously know that [`lib`](http://perldoc.perl.org/lib.html) works on the `@INC` array.  However, you appear to be thinking of it as an array of a single value that is replaced by subsequent usage.

Borodin's already explained the mechanisms well, and the docs for `lib` do an even better job.  However, perhaps a little example script will help:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dump qw(dump);

# Set @INC to minimum required for lib
BEGIN {
    require lib;
    @INC = $INC{'lib.pm'} =~ s/lib.pm//r;
    print "\@INC = " . dump(@INC) . "\n\n";
}

# Try adding two directories

use lib 'foo';
BEGIN {
    print "use lib 'foo';\n";
    print "# \@INC is " . dump(@INC) . "\n\n";
}

use lib 'bar';
BEGIN {
    print "use lib 'bar';\n";
    print "# \@INC is " . dump(@INC) . "\n\n";
}

# Remove a directory

no lib 'foo';
BEGIN {
    print "no lib 'foo';\n";
    print "# \@INC is " . dump(@INC) . "\n";
}
```

Outputs:

```
@INC = "C:/strawberry/perl/lib/"

use lib 'foo';
# @INC is ("foo", "C:/strawberry/perl/lib/")

use lib 'bar';
# @INC is ("bar", "foo", "C:/strawberry/perl/lib/")

no lib 'foo';
# @INC is ("bar", "C:/strawberry/perl/lib/")
```

Answer (score 1):

See the perl doc on `use lib`: http://perldoc.perl.org/lib.html

When script.pl runs, it will prepend "dir2" to `@INC`. It will then look for module1 in the directories listed in `@INC` starting with "dir2".

When it is loading module1, it will prepend "dir1" to `@INC` and then look for and load module2 in the directories now listed in `@INC`, which starts with dir1, then dir2 and then the remaining directories in `@INC`. Once it has loaded module2, it will finish loading module1.

The `use module2` line in script.pl will be ignored at this point.